# Storing values in a 2D array through function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I wrote the below code to generate the 26 neighborhood voxels of a 3D coordinate point taken as user input. I have used a function nbr26 which generates the neighboring voxels' coordinate values but getting the below error and warning.

```
plane.c: In function ‘nbr26’:
plane.c:28:18: error: **expected expression before ‘{’ token**

Arr[26][3] = {{p0-1,q0,r0},{p0+1,q0,r0},{p0,q0-1,r0},{p0,q0+1,r0},{p0,q0,r0-1},{p0,q0,r0+1},{p0-1,q0-1,r0},{p0+1,q0-1,r0},{p0-1,q0+1,r0},{p0+1,q0+1,r0},{p0-1,q0,r0-1},{p0+1,q0,r0-1},{p0-1,q0,r0+1},{p0+1,q0,r0+1},{p0,q0-1,r0-1},{p0,q0-1,r0+1},{p0,q0+1,r0-1},{p0,q0+1,r0+1},{p0-1,q0-1,r0-1},{p0-1,q0-1,r0+1},{p0-1,q0+1,r0-1},{p0-1,q0+1,r0+1},{p0+1,q0-1,r0-1},{p0+1,q0-1,r0+1},{p0+1,q0+1,r0-1},{p0+1,q0+1,r0+1}};
              ^

plane.c:29:5: warning: **return from incompatible pointer type** [enabled by default]
 return Arr;
 ^
```

Please have a look and shade some light on the problem !!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int** nbr26(int, int, int, int[][3]);
int main()
{
    int x0, y0, z0, a, b, c, d, Ar[26][3];

    printf("\nPlease enter a point on the plane : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x0, &y0, &z0);

    printf("\nPlease enter a norm of the plane : ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

    printf("\nUser Input");
    printf("\n(%d,%d,%d)", x0, y0, z0);
    printf("\t<%d,%d,%d>", a, b, c);
    d = -a*x0-b*y0-c*z0;
    printf("\nScaler Equation of the given plane is : %dx+%dy+%dz+  (%d)=0", a, b, c, d);

    int** ra = nbr26(x0,y0,z0,Ar);
    printf("\n26 neighbours of the given point are : ");
    printf("(%d,%d,%d)\n",x0-1,y0-1,z0-1);
    return 0;
}
int** nbr26(int p0, int q0, int r0, int Arr[26][3])
{
    Arr[26][3] = {{p0-1,q0,r0},{p0+1,q0,r0},{p0,q0-1,r0},{p0,q0+1,r0}, {p0,q0,r0-1},{p0,q0,r0+1},{p0-1,q0-1,r0},{p0+1,q0-1,r0},{p0-1,q0+1,r0},{p0+1,q0+1,r0},{p0-1,q0,r0-1},{p0+1,q0,r0-1},{p0-1,q0,r0+1},{p0+1,q0,r0+1},{p0,q0-1,r0-1},{p0,q0-1,r0+1},{p0,q0+1,r0-1},{p0,q0+1,r0+1},{p0-1,q0-1,r0-1},{p0-1,q0-1,r0+1},{p0-1,q0+1,r0-1},{p0-1,q0+1,r0+1},{p0+1,q0-1,r0-1},{p0+1,q0-1,r0+1},{p0+1,q0+1,r0-1},{p0+1,q0+1,r0+1}};
    return Arr;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. You can init an array that way only when you declare it. You can use [memcpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) or other technics to do the job,

Comment: ...and a 2D array it isn't a pointer of pointers.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to initialize an array not in its declaration. This is not legal in C or C++. You can initialize it only together with its declaration.

The only thing you can do is setting directly values or copying into it from another array.

So basically you are forced to do either

```
void nbr26(int p0, int q0, int r0, int Arr[26][3])
{
  Arr[0][0] = p0 - 1;
  Arr[0][1] = q0;
  ...
}
```

either

```
void nbr26(int p0, int q0, int r0, int Arr[26][3])
{
  const int buffer[26][3] = {{p0-1,q0,r0}, ... };
  memcpy(Arr, buffer, 26*3*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Something like `int [1][2]` decays to `int (*)[2]`, never `int *`! An N-dimensional array is not the same as a 1D array.